# ERROR: Fail execute jetty, How fix it?

Tags: spring, jetty

I have a problem with my project. When i `mvn jetty:run` then occur a flowing error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.M1:run  (default-cli) on
>   project springDAT-service: Execution default-cli of goal org.e
>   clipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.M1:run failed: An API
>   incompatibility was encountered while executing
>   org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.M1:run: j
>   ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocal
>   Fields(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils$FieldCallback;
>   )V

Here file pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>edu.java.spring.service</groupId>
  <artifactId>springDAT-service</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>springDAT-service Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>springDAT-service</finalName>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    <argLine>-Xmx2524m</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-XDignore.symbol.file</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.0.M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArgs>-Xmx1048m -Xms536m
                        -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</jvmArgs>
                    <reload>manual</reload>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>lib</name>
                            <value>${basedir}/target/spring-mvc/WEB-INF/lib</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>3</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                            <port>8080</port>
                            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                        </connector>
                    </connectors>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <webXml>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <classesDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</classesDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix different version of Spring. In your pom, you have two versions, which probably can generate this kind of conflict.

Spring ORM use 4.2.4, all others Spring dependencies use 4.0.3

Align the version in the pom, use 4.2.4 for all your Spring dependencies.